# Нужно ли заключать в кавычки слово "стеклокерамика"?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Нужно ли заключать в кавычки слово *стеклокерамика*?

Фраза звучит так:
Стеклокерамика "Ханса"

Answer (score 1):

Причин для постановки кавычек нет.